# How to delete files with `term/classID/` prefix, having name starts with `syllabus-` in S3 bucket in Java

Tags: java, amazon-s3

**How to bulk delete files in amazon S3 bucket?** 
I am trying to upload files to my S3 bucket, and once these files have been uploaded I want to bulk delete files with `term/classID/` prefix, having name starts with `syllabus-` in S3 bucket with Java.

the best option is to try delete them at one operation since accessing S3 is time costly in my case.

This is what I am doing currently, ( `path = "term/classID/", prefix="syllabus-"`) which is getting the files and then deleting those with `"syllabus-"` in their name.

```
   @Override
   public void deleteFilesWithPrefix( String path, String prefix ) throws IOException {
      ObjectListing objectsList = amazonS3Client.listObjects( bucketName, path );
      objectsList.getObjectSummaries().forEach( x -> deleteObjectsWithPrefix( x, prefix ) );

   }

   private void deleteObjectsWithPrefix( S3ObjectSummary x, String prefix ) {
      if ( x.getKey().contains( prefix ) ){
         s3Dao.deleteFile( bucketName, x.getKey() );
      }
   }
```

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/679989/most-efficient-way-to-batch-delete-s3-files

Comment: @KarolDowbecki, Thanks for replying. But this does not answer my question. the link talks more about deleting bulk objects assuming I know the keys. But I don't know the key, I just know a prefix of the object name.

Comment: I'm not sure there is an option to use a glob with S3, perhaps someone will explain.